# Stack overflow error

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am attempting to join add one XML file to another and I have found examples of how to do this.

I'm using Altova's XML-Spy (home). It is a 2006 copy which was free at the time!

However When I do the transformation it fails and I get the following message: XSLT stack overflow

Here is the xsl: 'updateFavourites.xml'

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="fileName" select=" 'CC_favourites.xml' " />
  <xsl:param name="updates" select="document($fileName)" />

  <xsl:variable name="updateFavourites" select="$updates/favourites/group" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="group">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="group[not(@id = $updateFavourites/@id)]" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateFavourites" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

target file to transform is 'camper_fav.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<favourites version="1">
<group name="camper contact">
    <item name="1: Parking" lat="156756060" lon="-3960972"/>
    <item name="2: Nationale Veenpark" lat="189918180" lon="25290936"/>
    <item name="3: Zeinissee" lat="169121412" lon="36456228"/>
    <item name="4: Brasserie De Holle Boom" lat="187314192" lon="19858932"/>
</group>
</favourites>
```

And the source file that I wish to add 'CC_favourites.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<favourites version="1">
    <group name="CC">
        <item name="Abbey Wood Caravan Club Site " lat="185350860" lon="430956"/>
        <item name="Aberbran Caravan Club Site " lat="187035158" lon="-12530027"/>
        <item name="Alderstead Heath Club Site " lat="184619520" lon="-499968"/>
        <item name="Gatwick Caravan Club Site " lat="184115484" lon="-727632"/>
        <item name="Ashridge Club Site " lat="187354760" lon="-511282"/>
    </group>
    <group name="CC CL">
        <item name="Burnside " lat="205635913" lon="-10403981"/>
        <item name="Greenpark " lat="205478189" lon="-9216606"/>
        <item name="Bridge House " lat="206721860" lon="-6786186"/>
        <item name="Smithy Croft " lat="207530951" lon="-7672927"/>
        <item name="The Croft Inn " lat="207509940" lon="-7790472"/>
    </group>
</favourites>
```

Please can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First one to mention that the title includes this site's name :)

Comment: I don't understand the problem, you say "wish to add" what do you mean? does it mean that you want to run CC_favourites.xml with the XSLT?

Comment: BTW: Running it with xsltproc (i.e. a different XSLT processor) also shows too deep nesting

Comment: I do in fact have several xml 'favoutites files that I wish to combine. They all containe a variety of groups which need to nested insides <favourites>

Answer (score 0):

Your script contains a recursive call to the template matching `group`. Since there is no obvious criterion to terminate the recursion you will end up exhausting the stack memory.

Replacing the match pattern to `favourites` will help (untested though):

```
<xsl:template match="favourites">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="group[not(@id = $updateFavourites/@id)]" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$updateFavourites" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```